# How to copy file between two windows machine using python

Tags: python, psexec

I have a task in hand where I need to copy some files from computer B to Computer A.
The script should be run from computer A

### Details|

Computer A- windows 7

Computer B - windows 7

### What i did ?

I used subprocess module to generate a command prompt and run simple copy command there.

```
 copy   \\computerB\users\abc.text c:\ComputerA\Test
```

however this method is not much successful and gives some random logon error.

### Note

No third party software is being used,For communication between two machines , i am using **psexec** module.

would prefer FtP server only if this is the only option left

Comment: This needs a lot more information. What are the operating systems, do you have access to both machines (for the development of the program), can you use SSH, do you have public keys installed, must it really use Python, ...?

Comment: Easiest way I found was to use a thirdparty binary with remote copy functionality. Something like Robocopy or win_copy and then wrap it with some python glue.

Comment: @graipher i have edited my question, i am using psexec instead of doing ssh, let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: @BoboDarph any other alternative u can suggest?

Comment: Regarding that error, have you tried executing one of those commands in the terminal and asking about the error you get? It might be that you are just missing the username or a password is needed.

Comment: the behavior is not consistent,sometimes it runs,sometime it fails,i am not providing username and password,since folder is shared

Comment: @pankajmishra Not really. The most resilient remote copy binary we could come up with in our CI infra was Robocopy and a bunch of batch jobs around it. Python or wmic, depends on what your poison is for glue. Windows machines are fidgety when it comes to trusting other windows machines.